# When is the function called when there is a bean of its class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache, ehcache-3

I want to set up caching in Spring Boot using EhCache 3 and Spring Caching. How do I set up the cache creation? Under what circumstances is the `customize()` method of `JCacheManagerCustomizer` called?

The cache is for Spring Security ACLs. At the end I need an AclCache.

I got these beans configured in the application class.

```
@Bean
public AclCache aclCache(Cache cache, PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy, AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy) {
    return new SpringCacheBasedAclCache(cache, permissionGrantingStrategy, aclAuthorizationStrategy);
}

@Bean
public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy(DataSource dataSource, AclCache aclCache, AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy, PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy) {
    return new BasicLookupStrategy(dataSource, aclCache, aclAuthorizationStrategy, permissionGrantingStrategy);
}

@Bean
public JdbcMutableAclService jdbcMutableAclService(DataSource dataSource, LookupStrategy lookupStrategy, AclCache aclCache) {
    return new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy, aclCache);
}
```

In a seperate class I got these beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new JCacheCacheManager(Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public Cache cache(CacheManager cacheManager, JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer) {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("aclCache");
        return cache;
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return new JCacheManagerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
                org.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration<Object, Object> config = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                        .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                                ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                        .heap(100, EntryUnit.ENTRIES))
                        .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicy.NO_EXPIRY)
                        .build();
                cacheManager.createCache("aclCache", Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(config));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now the cache `aclCache` should be created, but isn't. According to this example [1] it should be. Placing a breakpoint in the `customize()` method shows, that it is not hit. The JCacheManagerCustomizer is called though.

[1] https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactjs/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/config/CacheConfig.java

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring everything yourself so you are effectively bypassing the auto-configuration (Spring Boot will not do anything since you've provided your own config).

It's unclear what you're doing with those `Cache` exposed as beans as they aren't going to be picked up by your cache manager. Regardless of that, just invoke that code from the first method that creates the `CacheManager` since you are creating it yourself.